# Concurent.futures -multithreading -how do I match the result with the thread that produced the results?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this code:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed,wait
params = range(1,10)
def f(param):
  res=param*param
  return res

ex=ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) 
tasks = [ex.submit(f, param ) for param in params ]
finished=as_completed(tasks)
for r in finished:
  print (r.result())
```

How do I match the results with the param without function f returing the param ?
In a random case the output looks like this

```
25
4
9
1
16
36
49
64
```

Update:
the function I am using in reality is called conn.send_command() which takes as param a command. the conn object has built in properties, one of them is the IP of the device that I am sending the commnand to. I need to pair the output of the command (returned by conn.send_command(x) with the IP of the device>
I have no control over the conn object as it is defined in an imported module which I do not want to change and I do not want to create another object based on the conn object

OK the code that works is this

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed,wait
params = range(1,10)
def f(param):
  param=param*param
  return param

ex=ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) 
tasks = {param:ex.submit(f, param ) for param in params }
finished=as_completed(tasks)
for param,r in tasks.items():
  print (param,r.result())
```

Comment: For most use cases for thread pools you shouldn't care which thread produced the result. You could always return the parameters passed to the function if you need the calling parameters `return param, res`

Comment: that is the whole point of the question, I need an mechanism external to the function that could do that. Otherwise I would need to change a lots of code

Comment: What exactly do you need? The original function and arguments for every result?

Comment: I have another idea, but first let me ask -- do you need to identity the unique threads (in this case there are 5) or the unique invocations of `f` (in this case there are 9)?

Comment: please see the updates

Comment: What is a `conn`?

Comment: a conn is a connection object ..it should not matter that much for the matter discussed. I made the problem easier saying that it has a property called conn.ip that is the IP if the device I am connected to via that conn object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign each task to an IP when you submit them as a dict

```
 tasks = {device.ip: ex.submit(f, device.param) for device in devices}
```

`tasks` will then then be a dictionary of IPs and tasks

```
for ip, task in tasks.items():
    print(ip, r.result())
```

Comment: let's play with this one https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/221310f6-4c63-4879-84e6-6491e0a621ef/?i=true

Comment: thanks that works, quick question....why are you iterating over tasks and not over results ?

Comment: The tasks dictionary has the IP and the task that was submitted for that IP. Tasks only contained the tasks being run and they didn't have the IP

Comment: so we have tasks and finished. Tasks is a dictionary of IPs and results. Finished is just a vector of future objects as far as I understand. It seems a little bit confusing and redundant. the as completed method seems to work with the future obejcts only